# get-параметры пропадают из запроса при 301 редиректе

Tags: wordpress, apache, http-status-code-301

Здравствуйте. Может кто сталкивался: сайт на **wordpress**, не **woocommerce**, реализован простой фильтр цены (товары - **посты**, цены - **ACF**). Фильтр по сабмиту запрашивает страницу с **GET**-параметрами. Происходит запрос, редиректит 301м туда же, но уже без **GET**. Имеется стандартный вордпрессовский **.htaccess**, при простых и при произвольных ссылках - одинаковое поведение. На сервере перенаправления не выставлялись.

Основной вопрос - почему 301 на себя же (а не 200) и без параметров?

Разрабы cделали так: в **`category.php`** впилили **`jQuery UI`** ренжбар и там же (**`category.php`**) ловили **`GET`** с диапазоном цен, там же формировали запрос на выборку с этими параметрами. Цены для ренжа - через запрос в `wp_postmeta` на выборку **`min/max`** нужных **`custom fields`**, но там всё в порядке. Сайт попал к нам, мы перенесли его на другой хост (**`apache`**), настроили зеркала. Я так понимаю, что до того работало, иначе как заказчик принимал работу хз (мы не чекали фильтры при переносе). Было бы понятно, если бы срабатывали зеркала, но все линки в экшенах форм фильтров строго прямые (**`https`**), а **`301`** всё равно происходит.

З.Ы. пересадил формы на **POST** - проблем нет, функционал восстановлен. Но вопрос остаётся. Буду благодарен за разъяснение.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: .htaccess приложите в вопрос (не все в курсе какой он у wp стандартный).

Comment: А чем и как реализован фильтр? Сам по себе WP c ACF так себя не ведет.

Comment: @KAGG Design разрабы cделали так: в category.php впилили ЮИ ренж бар и  там же (category.php) ловили GET с диапазоном цен, там же формировали запрос на выборку с этими параметрами. Цены для ренжа - через запрос в wp_postmeta на выборку нужных CF, но там всё в порядке. Сайт попал к нам, мы перенесли его на другой хост (apache), настроили зеркала. Я так понимаю, что до того работало, иначе как заказчик принимал работу хз (мы не чекали фильтры при переносе). Было бы понятно, если бы срабатывали зеркала, но все линки в экшенах форм фильтров строго прямые (https), а 301 всё равно происходит.

Comment: Ничего не понятно. "ЮИ ренж бар" - неизвестная мне примочка. Даже не слышал о ней никогда. Код покажите, иначе вообще ни чем разговор. Как мне воспроизвести на своем сайте вашу ситуацию? И да, а в чем проблема с 301?

Answer (score 1):

если у  вас редирект на nginx или php нужно указывать урл для редиректа включая get параметры так как они тоже являются частю вашего URL

вы идете на сервер с запросом того урла который говорит что данный url находится по другому аддресу и дает его приэтом он не говорит  что туда нужно передавать теже параметры

помоему так это выглядит на nginx

`return 301 https://www.example.com$uri$is_args$args;`

Answer (score 0):

Любой редирект будет выполнен с кодом 30x. Это код именно редиректа. Поэтому остается смотреть как на backend был реализован редирект.

Для nginx @medve_dev уже ответил, но можно улучшить **$scheme://$server_name$request_uri;**

Для apache необходимо не забывать флаг **[QSA]**

И в приложении, разумеется: **$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']**